# What does the phrase "shadows dance on the gravel underneath it" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a sentence:

> Sunlight kisses the yellow leaves of a tree by the lake, as shadows
>   dance on the gravel underneath it.

I am not sure about the phrase ""shadows dance on the gravel underneath it". Is the gravel underneath the tree or the lake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Underneath it" refers to the noun-phrase "a tree by the lake". If the gravel were underneath the lake, then nobody would be able to see it, and the sunlight would find it hard to make shadows dance on it.